# Expresión regular que empiece con mayúscula que y tenga un minimo y maximo de caracteres

Tags: c#, regex

Necesito una expresion regular que valide que un string que le mando inicie con mayuscula, tenga un minimo de 5 caracteres y un maximo de 32, hasta ahora el codigo que tengo no me lleva ningun count al match no se si estoy escribiendo mal la expresion regular

````
    {
        public List <string> validationRegex(string inbound)

            {

                string rx = "^[A-Z].{5,32}$";

                Regex regex = new Regex(rx);

                string lol= "Leon1";
          
                List<string> error = new List<string>();

                MatchCollection match = regex.Matches(lol);                

                foreach (var item in match)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }

                

            
            return error;


            }
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

La expresión regular está correcta , creo que el error está en el foreach, el tipo de dato que retorna es Match , revise éste ejemplo, [ejemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection?view=net-6.0)